# Bernoulli equation from energy conservation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation

I have derived the energy conservation equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left [ \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 + \varepsilon + \rho \phi \right ] + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left [ \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 v_j + \rho h v_j + \rho \phi v_j \right ]=0
\end{equation}

where $\varepsilon$ is internal energy and $\rho \phi$ is the gravitational energy. 
I was trying to derive the [Bernoulli equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle) from the above equation for time independent flow. It is not clear to me which term is Bernoulli equation term. How  can derive the Bernoulli equation?

Comment: what is h and $\epsilon$?

Comment: @RonMaimon h is the enthalpy

Comment: actually I hope your energy equation is right, otherwise my Bernoulli's law is wrong :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I was trying to derive the Bernoulli equation from the above equation
>   for *time independent* flow

If you are studying something *time independent* then you just let $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ to be zero:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left [ \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 v_j + \rho h v_j + \rho \phi v_j \right ]=0
$$

Next step is to get rid of $\rho$. Bernoulli's equation doesn't contain $\rho$, does it? We'll need mass balance for the stationary state:

$$\frac{\partial \rho v_j}{\partial x_j} = 0$$

which together with the first equation leads to:
$$
\rho v_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left [ \frac{1}{2} v^2 + h + \phi \right ]=0
$$

Now one should recall that Bernoulli's law is valid only along streamlines/pathlines, which do coincide for a steady flow. If something called $A$ is constant along the vector field $\boldsymbol v$, then it should suffice the equation

$$v_j \frac{\partial A}{\partial x_j} = 0$$

Actually it is just a derivative of $A$ along the vector field $\boldsymbol v$ --- if the derivative is zero then $A$ is constant along the vector field.

Thus we got the Bernoulli's law:

$$
\frac{1}{2} v^2 + h + \phi = const
$$

along the streamline/pathline for the stationary case.